# Numpy array remove duplicates with if statement

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, numpy

I have a NumPy string array in the shape of (112, 7). First few elements are just letters and the rest is numbers like follows

```
List[0] = array(['ID32', 'TRED', 'PLUS', '434','0.34', '11.9', '4.8'], dtype='<U14')
List[1] = array(['ID32', 'TRED', 'PLUS', '994','0.84', '44.3', '1.11'], dtype='<U14')
List[2] = array(['ID32', 'PROP', 'MINUS', '234','0.56', '44.3', '1.11'], dtype='<U14')
```

....

What I would like to achieve is the IF statement check the first three elements and if they are identical calculate the ratio of fourth and 5th element and remove the smaller one from the list

For instance `List[0]` and `List[1]` have same first three elements so checking the ratios (`434/0.34 = 1276.5`, `994/0.84 = 1183`), so `List[1]` is smaller and should be removed from the list.

Here is my failed attempt

```
for i, val in enumerate(List):
    if val[i][0] == val[i][1]
        print(val[3].astype(np.float)/val[4].astype(np.float))
```

I appreciate any help.

Comment: If you are open to using `pandas` it can be easily done.

Comment: @HenryYik Sure, can you please give an example? I do not have much experience with pandas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are open to using `pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd


# setup
l = [['ID32', 'TRED', 'PLUS', '434', '0.34', '11.9', '4.8'],
     ['ID32', 'TRED', 'PLUS', '994', '0.84', '44.3', '1.11'],
     ['ID32', 'PROP', 'MINUS', '234', '0.56', '44.3', '1.11']]

df = pd.DataFrame(l)

print (df.assign(ratio=df[3].astype(float)/df[4].astype(float))
         .sort_values([0,1,2,"ratio"], ascending=False)
         .drop_duplicates([0,1,2], keep="first")
         .sort_index()
         .drop("ratio", 1)
         .to_numpy())
```

Result:

```
[['ID32' 'TRED' 'PLUS' '434' '0.34' '11.9' '4.8']
 ['ID32' 'PROP' 'MINUS' '234' '0.56' '44.3' '1.11']]
```

Comment: This is clever but it will change the order of all rows by `sort_values`...not sure if that matters.

Comment: let me throw in a `sort_index` after `drop_duplicates` to retain original order :-)

Answer (score 0):

First make a mask to track which rows to keep, and convert the numeric columns:

```
keep = np.ones(len(arr), bool) # [True, True, True]
numer = arr[:,3].astype(float)
denom = arr[:,4].astype(float)
```

Then a loop to edit the mask of which rows we want to keep:

```
for ii in range(1, len(arr)): 
    if np.all(arr[ii-1,:3] == arr[ii,:3]): 
        if numer[ii-1] / denom[ii-1] < numer[ii] / denom[ii]: 
            keep[ii-i] = False 
        else: 
            keep[ii] = False
```

Now you have `keep` as `array([ True, False,  True])`, which you can easily use to get the final result:

```
arr[keep]
```

Giving you:

```
array([['ID32', 'TRED', 'PLUS', '434', '0.34', '11.9', '4.8'],
       ['ID32', 'PROP', 'MINUS', '234', '0.56', '44.3', '1.11']],
      dtype='<U14')
```

If the number of matching strings is small compared with the total number of rows, this might be faster:

```
matches = 1 + np.where((xxx[1:] == xxx[:-1]).all(1))[0] # [1]
for ii in matches: # now we already know the strings match
    if numer[ii-1] / denom[ii-1] < numer[ii] / denom[ii]: 
        keep[ii-i] = False 
    else: 
        keep[ii] = False
```

That way the code is still quite readable but the loop is only iterating the number of matches, not the number of rows.